# Lightning Web Component Open Source

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

When I try to create the project with lwc oss it comes to nothing, stops at the attached image part and does not progress. Do you know why this could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: it shouldn't, how many times have you tried? can you paste the command you used to run the scafolder?

Comment: yesterday, like five times! npx create-lwc-app facaNegra  , and then : yes , Standard web app, and yes!

Comment: is you internet connection stable ?

Comment: yes.. i have no problems